# Can't Use a Headset in Ubuntu Mate

Tags: sound, audio-jack

I'm running into an issue when trying to use a headset with my PC. The sound just isn't coming from the headphones. I don't know why this would be the case, as sound is coming out of my PC's speakers.

I'm using release 16.04.4 LTS (Xenial Xerus) 64-bit, and I'm running on an Alienware 15 R2.

Comment: try to use pavucontrol to manipulate the sound output. you can download it with `sudo apt install pavucontrol` . open it from the menu and toggle the sound output and see if it works

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I can change the audio port and it recognizes that I have a headset plugged in, but the audio continues to play out of my laptop's speakers.

Comment: How is the headset connected to the computer? Analogue "[phone connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_(audio)#Computer_sound)" audio cables? USB? Bluetooth? Something else?

Comment: It seems allot like a "phone connector", but it has two separate ports for audio and microphone.